# How to log off in the dynamic crm

Tags: dynamics-crm

I  log in the dynamic CRM and I want to use a another account to log in again. How to log off the CRM system?? I have cleaned the cookies and it doesn't work.How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CRM Online, you can use the "Sign Out" link in upper right hand corner of the page.

If you are running On Premise you will have to take a few extra steps as CRM is looking for your Active Directory credentials. An easy way would be to change the security settings in Internet Explorer so that you are prompted to enter credentials.

Security Settings -> Local Intranet -> Custom Level - Uncheck Automatic login with current username and password

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892666

Comment: This is slightly odd question. Why would you want to sign out from CRM? if you want to login as a different user, Ctrl + Shift + Right Click on IE and click on 'Run as a Different User'.

Comment: I'm floored all of the replies refer to IE. Is there a way to log out in Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

For those using **Safari for OSX** login to **Dynamics CRM on Premise**, if you didn't use Keychain to store password for this site, you will clear the connection when you turn off Safari.

But if you use Keychain to store, you need to use Keychain Access and manually remove password related to Dynamics CRM. Then turn off your browser. You authentication cookie will be killed. When you reopen Safari and browse Dynamics CRM, if will prompt and ask for password again.

[Log Off Microsoft Dynamics CRM on Premise from Safari on OSX](https://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/log-off-microsoft-dynamics-crm-on-premise-from-safari-on-osx/)